# How can i initialize path of image in Flutter as here File _image cannot be Non-nullable?

Tags: flutter, file, image-upload, imagepicker

I am trying to get Image from Gallery source using ImagePicker but for that, i first need to initialize path of image.

```
  File _image;
```

Please help me i am begginer.
Here is my Code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'; // For File Upload To Firestore
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart'; // For Image Picker
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';


class ImageUpload extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageUpload({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageUploadState createState() => _ImageUploadState();
}

class _ImageUploadState extends State<ImageUpload> {
  late String imageUrl;
  File _image;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Upload Image"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Add Image here"),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepPurple)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: _image == null
                            ? Center(child: Text('No Image Selected'))
                            : Image.file(_image)),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // uploadImage();
                          getImage();
                        },
                        child: Text("Select Image"))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image as File;
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }

  uploadPic(File _image) async {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    String url = '';
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child("image" + DateTime.now().toString());
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image);
    uploadTask.whenComplete(() {
      url = ref.getDownloadURL() as String;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
    return url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final picker = ImagePicker();
```

Initialize path of Image like this

```
PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

File _image = File(pickedFile.path);
```

Comment: Can you make appropriate changes in above code and show me how to initialize??

Comment: I think the problem you have is here:  `Future getImage() async {
    XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {  setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });}
  
  }` Also, make it File? image